# Delete rows from A2 to the end of the column in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am try to come up a code in VBA the will delete from A2(row 2) to the end of rows

```
Option Explicit
Sub Ticket()
    Dim a As Long
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    a = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fleet Report").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
    MsgBox "Last Row is " & a

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fleet Report").Rows("3:a").EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

But I got error message: type mismatch. Does anyone has an idea?

[image]

Comment: "3:" & a (comment too short)

Comment: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fleet Report").Rows("3" & a).EntireRow.Delete; there is no error, but it didn't  delete the rows

Answer (score 2):

Your line of code for deleting is incorrectly written. It reads:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fleet Report").Rows("3:a").EntireRow.Delete
```

When it should say:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fleet Report").Rows("3:" & a).EntireRow.Delete
```

Also to avoid row and column numbers, which I personally am not a fan of, you could format it as:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fleet Report").Range("A3:A" & a).EntireRow.Delete
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Ticket()
Dim a As Long
Dim WB As Workbook, WS As Worksheet



Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
Set WS = WB.Worksheets("Fleet Report")
Application.Calculation = xlManual
a = WS.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row


MsgBox "Last Row is " & a
```

Comment: "Try this: {code dump}" are rather poor answers IMO. Why not take 2 seconds to [edit] your post and spell out what the solution is and why it works, instead of encouraging blind copy-pasta coding?

Comment: Because 2 other people post answers before I can get a chance to try and answer. My code types the objects first, then sets them individually, one at a time, so the original poster can step through his code and see each line execute.

Comment: Protip: other answers don't matter if yours is better ;-) ..also you can always [edit] it after it's posted.

Comment: I will try that! : )